# Ansible roles throwing error @/root/roles:/root:/etc/ansible/roles

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and I have created my first Ansible role playbook and when I tried to run it it is throwing the error below, whereas other modules apart from the roles (like handler, templates) are working fine. I am observing this issue only with the roles in the playbook.

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - nginx
```

```
ERROR! the role 'nginx' was not found in /root/roles:/root:/etc/ansible/roles

The error appears to have been in '/root/server.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - nginx
      ^ here
```

In the `ansible.cng` file I have specified the path as `roles_path    = /etc/ansible/roles`

Kindly let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: And where is `nginx` directory with your role located?

Comment: It is located at /etc/ansible/roles/ngnix

Comment: What's the result of `ls -l /etc/ansible/roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml`?

Comment: Hi ,  There is nothing created under /etc/ansible/roles/nginx/.                                                                                                             root@ubuntu-96:/etc/ansible/roles/ngnix# ls -l
total 0

Answer (score 1):

Because Ansible not found nginx role in folders /root/roles, /root, /etc/ansible/roles or local ./roles.

If you want to use a role named nginx, ansible will try to load a file nginx/tasks/main.yml in one of your roles folders.

Copy into your nginx role folder this code : https://github.com/jdauphant/ansible-role-nginx

And use it as described in its README.md